# SQL - multi selection on single field

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Here is my issue,

In a database, I have 2 distinct tables (**field_data_field_company_ref** and **node**) .

In the first one, I have two distinct fields : **entity_id** and **field_company_ref_nid** . They refer to a single key (**nid**) in the other table.

I'd like a result which shows the two first fields having taken the value of **title**, which is a field in the second table, thanks to the **nid** key

With this code :

```
SELECT node.title as "Entity" ,node.title as 'Company ' 
  FROM `field_data_field_company_ref`,`node` 
  WHERE bundle = 'project' and (`entity_id` = node.nid 
    OR `field_company_ref_nid` = node.nid )
```

The result gave me duplicated value...

An other code :

```
SELECT node.title as "Entity" 
  FROM `field_data_field_company_ref`,`node` 
  WHERE bundle = 'project' and `entity_id` = node.nid 
UNION 
SELECT node.title as 'Company ' 
  FROM `field_data_field_company_ref`,`node` 
  WHERE bundle = 'project' and `field_company_ref_nid` = node.nid
```

gives me unique column (*Entity*)

Could you help me please? It something like this I'd like to have
[image]

Comment: `I think it'll be easy for you` ... for Gordon Linoff maybe, not for most other people.  Could you edit your question by adding sample data and your desired output?

Comment: Unions must have same structure.  It combines rows, not columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can join the `table2` twice with `table1` like this:

```
select 
    b.title title1,
    c.title title2
from table1 a
join table2 b on a.entity_id = b.nid
join table2 c on a.field_company_ref_nid = c.nid;
```

Comment: Great answer ! I can now go further in my dev :)

Comment: Really @GurV?  Just copy an existing answer and update the column names after the OP updates their question.  Bad form.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you are wanting to lookup the values of both entity and company from node which holds the text labels for them.  If that is the case you need this.

```
SELECT entity.title as "Entity" ,company.title as 'Company ' 
  FROM `field_data_field_company_ref`
    LEFT JOIN `node` as entity
    ON entity.nid = `entity_id`
    LEFT JOIN `node` as company
    ON company.nid = `field_company_ref_nid`
  WHERE bundle = 'project'
```

Comment: thx! I see what you do, but it's still duplicate of 'entity.title'

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "still duplicate of 'entity.title'"  entity.title and company.title, if your column values are correct, will be separate values based on entity_id or field_company_ref_nid

Comment: with the code you gave me, in the 2 columns, it gives me the same value --> entity.title ...